# Understanding the meaning of "Eructation of unhealthy souls" in T.S. Eliot's Burnt Norton

Tags: meaning, poetry, t-s-eliot

In the third section of Burnt Norton we find these lines

> Eructation of unhealthy souls
> Into the faded air, the torpid

[Eructation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eructation) have two meanings

1. Belching
2. Eruption

So, if we take up the second meaning then "eructation of unhealthy souls" could mean death, that is soul is erupting out of the body.

Taking up the first meaning and considering this [chat discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55339836#55339836), we find few things that requires little explanation. First, how belching is related to souls? And after all what does "**unhealthy** souls" mean? Does this belching have some biblical refernces of what [North](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/334627) found and quoted :

> Revelations 3:16
> So, because you are lukewarm - neither hot nor cold - I am about to spit you out of my mouth

If we take up the first meaning of "Eructation" from above, and refer to [Tsundoku's](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/226081) paraphrase

> a haunting evocation of commuters traveling by tube to work.
> The metro belches forth the commuters

Then it becomes strange as suddenly commuters and metros have come up in the poem. As I say, every line of Burnt Norton seems unconnected, [Minute by minute they change](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43289/easter-1916).